# Checkbox toggle is not working properly in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have my toggle for checkbox in my application. It's not working.

I have tried using onChange function but it's not working.

---

**Checkbox**

```
<input 
    id="switchCheckboxInputAssert" 
    className="switch-checkbox-input" 
    type="checkbox" 
    checked={this.state.option.assert == 1 ? true : false} 
    value={this.state.option.assert} 
    onChange={this.assertChange}
    disabled={!this.props.canBeSolution} 
/>
```

**onChange function**

```
assertChange = () =>
    this.setState({
        option: { ...this.state.option, assert: !this.state.option.assert }
    })
```

How can I toggle my checkbox properly?

Comment: Your code is [working fine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vta8he). Just check what you are getting as `this.props.canBeSolution` true / false.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're mixing up [controlled and uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) components/elements. If you want to allow the checkbox to toggle you should rather pass the value as the default value instead of the value, and pass the checked value to your callback

```
<input
  id="switchCheckboxInputAssert"
  className="switch-checkbox-input"
  type="checkbox"
  // pass state value as default checked value
  defaultChecked={this.state.option.assert}
  // pass checked value to callback
  onChange={evt => this.assertChange(evt.target.checked)}
  disabled={!this.props.canBeSolution}
/>
```

[image: Edit intelligent-mayer-ve1i9]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `value` attribute, just use `checked` attribute without any logic as you are already taking care of login inside `assertChange` function for checkbox in react.

```
<input
  id="switchCheckboxInputAssert"
  className="switch-checkbox-input"
  type="checkbox"
  checked={this.state.option.assert}
  onChange={this.assertChange}
   />
```

working demo

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
state = {
  option: {
    'something': 'new something',
    assert: true
  }
}
  assertChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      option: { ...this.state.option, assert: !this.state.option.assert }
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.option)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          id="switchCheckboxInputAssert"
          className="switch-checkbox-input"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.option.assert}
          onChange={this.assertChange}
           />
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!